# How to resolve service instance of Autofac container in Main method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I need to get an instance in `Program.cs` using ASP.NET Core 6 with Autofac.

Example:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                   .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                   .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(conf =>
                         {
                             conf.UseStartup<StartupBuild>();
                         })
                   .Build();
            
    var serviceInstance = host.Services.GetService<ISomeService>();
}
```

The `ISomeService` is registered in `ConfigureServices` of `StartupBuild` class.

Problem: `serviceInstance` cannot be resolved. I'm getting an error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name"

from `Autofac.ResolutionExtensions`. What's the correct way when using Autofac?

**Edit:** The `ISomeService` has been registered with `services.TryAddTransient` in `IServiceCollection`.
The resolution of `ISomeService` is successful when removing the line

> .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? JIC Is `ISomeService` registered as keyed dependency?

Comment: See my edits above

Comment: Sorry, seems to be false alarm. Something else is wrong.

Comment: NP. That's why making a [mre] is useful.